# N Red Eye Dragons Puzzle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, induction

There are ***N* red-eyed dragons** on the island, and they leave at midnight if they know their own eye color (which is either red or blue). The traveler says, ***"I've never seen such beautiful red eyes!"***

**In reality, all dragons have red eyes. What happens to the dragons?**

**My solution** is as follows:

The traveler essentially hinted that **there is at least one red-eyes dragon**.

If the dragons see **N-1 Blue eyes** then they would know they have red eyes and will leave on **1st night.**
But Since in reality all dragons have red-eyes, each dragon stays the first day. Then on the 2nd day, all dragons know that every other dragon stayed last day because they didn't see **N-1 blue eyes** and that means every dragon will know their have red-eyes and will leave on **2nd night.**

I want to know **whether my solution is right or not** and if its not right then **what thinking steps** would I need to make it right?(**Am I missing something important**?)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a very well known problem, easily researched online.  [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/the-blue-eyed-islanders-puzzle/) for instance.

Comment: Many questions have been asked about this on [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blue-eyes).

Answer (score 0):

If you go onto YouTube and type in "TedEd Green Eyes Riddle" you will see this problem worded differently (same scenario, but green eyed people stuck under a dictator's influence).

In fact, on a lot of other TedEd riddle videos, this riddle is jokingly referenced in a lot of the comments.